# Location Background - Network Connection

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to post data on background and I want to receive response from in regular interval that so that I am trying to use CLLocation Manager . But didUpdateToLocation method calling only once.
Please suggest me !
enter code here

```
    - (void)applicationDidEnterBackgroundUIApplication *)application
    {
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; // whenever we move
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest; // 100 m
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

    bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
     bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];

    // Start the long-running task and return immediately.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_ QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    //Do the work associated with the task
    // code for Posting Data Here
    NSLog(@"backgroundTimeRemaining: %f", [[UIApplication sharedApplication] backgroundTimeRemaining]);
    [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    });

    }
    - (void)locationManagerCLLocationManager *)manager
       didUpdateToLocationCLLocation *)newLocation
       fromLocationCLLocation *)oldLocation
     {

      NSLog(@"Location Change");
     } 
     This Method Call Only Once.
```

Comment: Have you moved around some? I know from experience that even with kCLDistanceFilterNone you may need to move rather far (sometimes more than 30 meters) to actually get it to send the update.

Comment: According to u what should be the value of locationManager.distanceFilter for getting location update.

Comment: That is a good value. However, depending on where you are, the phone may not get a very good fix on your location. Thus, even though it is set to notify you whenever you it moves even a meter, it might not know it has moved a meter.

Comment: One other thing to look for is where you are calling stopUpdatingLocation and debug to ensure it is not getting called.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not testing this in simulator.
You don't get location updates on the iphone simulator.

Comment: I am testing this on device but yet method called only once

Answer (score 0):

In order to run location services in the background, you need to modify your plist such that the UIBackgroundModes key contains location.

Comment: I allready modify my apps plist as                               Required background modes : App registers for location updates

Comment: I'm not sure if you need this or not, but does your plist also contain both *location-serivces* and *gps* under Required device capabilities?

Answer (score 0):

the call should be

```
    [locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
```